# Issue using Dotnetzip in powershell error consider setting UseZip64WhenSaving

Tags: powershell

I have used dotnetzip in c# with large files with no problem. I have a requirement to zip up some large files in the power shell. I see from dotnetzip docs I can use it iN ps .
But I keep getting the error
Compressed or Uncompressed size, or offset exceeds the maximum value. Consider setting the UseZip64WhenSaving property on the ZipFile instance.
this is my PS code. How do I set the UseZip64WhenSaving in PS?

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\\mybigfiles\\Ionic.Zip.dll");
$directoryToZip = "D:\\mybigfiles\\";
$zipfile =  new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile;
#$zipfile.UseZip64WhenSaving;
$e= $zipfile.AddEntry("mybig.csv", "This is a zipfile created from within powershell.")
$e= $zipfile.AddDirectory($directoryToZip, "home")
$zipfile.Save("D:\\mybigfiles\\big.zip");
$zipfile.Dispose();
```

Working C# code.

````
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
                zip.AddFile(compressedFileName);
                zip.AddFile("\\\\server\\bigfile\\CM_Report_20220411200326.csv");
                zip.AddFile("\\\\server\\bigfile\\PM_Report_20220411200326.csv");
                zip.AddFile("\\\\server\\bigfile\\SCE_Report_20220411200326.csv");
                
            }```
````

Comment: `$zipfile.UseZip64WhenSaving = 'AsNecessary'` should work (PowerShell loves implicit type conversion). Otherwise, make sure you use the qualified type name for the enum: `$zipfile.UseZip64WhenSaving = [Ionic.Zip.Zip64Option]::AsNecessary`

Comment: Note that in PowerShell you don't have to escape backslashes in string literals. E. g. `$directoryToZip = "D:\mybigfiles\"` will be fine.

Comment: Well it's not zipping my "mybig.csv" it is only "zipping" the text This is a zipfile created from within powershell. not the .csv file? Strange

Comment: @LJH might be a relative path resolution issue, try passing a rooted path instead (eg. `D:\some\path\mybig.csv` instead of just `mybig.csv`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike C#, PowerShell **loves implicit type conversions** - and it'll implicitly parse and convert a string value to its cognate enum value when you assign it to an enum-typed property:

```
$zipfile.UseZip64WhenSaving = 'AsNecessary'
```

Alternatively, make sure you qualify the enum type name:

```
#$zipfile.UseZip64WhenSaving = [Ionic.Zip.Zip64Option]::AsNecessary
```

It's also worth noting that *all PowerShell string literals act like **verbatim** strings in C#* - in other words, `\` is not a special character that needs to be escaped:

```
$directoryToZip = "D:\mybigfiles\"
# ...
$e = $zipfile.AddDirectory($directoryToZip, "home")
$zipfile.Save("D:\mybigfiles\big.zip")
```